# Android programmatically trigger long HOME press

Tags: android, keyevent

I am trying to figure out a way to programmatically mimic the action of a long HOME button press. I have BACK button working with following code:

`this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));`

But when I try to mimic a (long) HOME press same way:

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME));
// Thread.sleep(1000); Perhaps for long press?
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME));
```

Nothing happens. Is there any other way to mimic the HOME button press?

Comment: Just to for my knowledge I am asking this, May I know what is the main purpose of holding Long press Home button..?

Comment: actually I dont know how to do this, so I can't answer your question. But be aware that not all Android phones have the same behaviour when you longpress the home button. Some open the app switcher and other open a assistant. Also I wonder if you can ovveride the default behaviour of the button. Going to watch this question

Comment: Well, on the new Amazon Fire devices long pressing Home button triggers Alexa to listen, Which is what I want to achieve programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent((long) ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout(), (long) 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME), 0); // ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() returns the duration in milliseconds before a press turns into a long press
```

It uses this constructor:

```
/**
 * Create a new key event.
 *
 * @param downTime The time (in {@link android.os.SystemClock#uptimeMillis})
 * at which this key code originally went down.
 * @param eventTime The time (in {@link android.os.SystemClock#uptimeMillis})
 * at which this event happened.
 * @param action Action code: either {@link #ACTION_DOWN},
 * {@link #ACTION_UP}, or {@link #ACTION_MULTIPLE}.
 * @param code The key code.
 * @param repeat A repeat count for down events (> 0 if this is after the
 * initial down) or event count for multiple events.
 */
public KeyEvent(long downTime, long eventTime, int action,
                int code, int repeat) {
    mDownTime = downTime;
    mEventTime = eventTime;
    mAction = action;
    mKeyCode = code;
    mRepeatCount = repeat;
    mDeviceId = KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD;
}
```

See [this](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/05/override-home-button-in-android.html). It might help.